# jQuery not working on a jQuery generated HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generated multiple `li` in a string to have a dynamic display of a user list (connected or not).
At the end of the list, I added a `li` that's the button to disconnect.

Problem is, if I add it in my original code by default, without generating it, the `Ajax function` works fine.

If I generate it, it doesn't even apply the **preventDefault()**.

**Why is that, and how to fix this issue ?**

```
function displayUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getUsers.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (aUsers) {
        if (aUsers != null) {
            var sUserList = '';
            $.each(aUsers, function (key, oUser) {
                sUserList += '<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: springgreen;"></span>' + oUser.nickname + '</a></li>';
            });
            sUserList += '<li class="divider"></li>';
            sUserList += '<li class="disconnect"><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Sign Out</a></li>';
            $('ul.dropdown-menu').html(sUserList);
        } else {
            var sNoConnectionMessage = '<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" style="color: crimson;"></span>Aucune connexion en cours.</li>';
            sNoConnectionMessage += '<li class="divider"></li>';
            sNoConnectionMessage += '<li class="disconnect"><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Sign Out</a></li>';

            $('ul.dropdown-menu').html(sNoConnectionMessage);
        }
    });
}

setInterval(displayUsers, 1000);

$('li.disconnect a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'logoff.php'
    }).done(function () {
        $('div.LoginChat').removeClass('hide');
        $('div.WriteMessage').addClass('hide');
    })
});
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are attached to *elements*, not to *selectors*.

When you do this:

```
$('li.disconnect a').on('click', function (event) {
```

jQuery will identify matching elements for `'li.disconnect a'` once, and only once, at the time this line of code executes.  Any matching elements added to the DOM afterward will not have been identified.  In order to do that, you need to attach the click handler to a common parent element (which doesn't change during the life of the DOM) and use the overload of `.on()` which filters events from child elements.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.disconnect a', function (event) {
```

This will attach the handler to the `document` element (though any common parent element will work) instead of the identified elements.  As events "bubble up" through the DOM they will eventually reach that parent element.  The second selector in the `.on()` function then filters those child elements to respond only to click events which originated from an identified element.

I've written more on the subject [here](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and delegate the click handler to something that doesn't get regenerated, such as the `document`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.disconnect a' function (event) {
    ...
});
```

The issue is if you don't delegate to something higher, the event handler is lost when you destroy the element.